# USB printer needs to be "initialized" via virtual machine in order to work

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, drivers, printing

I have an HP printer, model ENVY 4500.

It used to work smoothly in Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04.

In June I upgraded to 20.04. Since then I have not been able to have it work properly: it is correctly recognized but when I try printing anything, it prints half page then it hangs. Same problem with the scanner.

I happen to use quite often a Lubuntu 16.04 VirtualBox virtual machine and I discovered by chance that if I release the USB printer *after* that it has been "captured" by the virtual machine, then the printer works smoothly in 20.04. The scanner is fixed too.

My guess is there is a USB device driver problem in 20.04 which in some way is fixed when the printer is initialized in the virtual machine, but I am not able to figure out what this proble is and how to fix it once for all in 20.04 so that I don't have to go through this annoying workaround to use the printer.

Comment: The printer (HP printer model ENVY 4500) has built in Ethernet. Put it on your network (router) and then install the driver in Ubuntu as a network driver. That will work better.

Comment: @John The printer has built in WiFi, not Ethernet. For some reason unclear to me, it is not able to connect to my WiFi network.

Comment: I can also add that I tried to connect the printer to the computer in my office (which also runs Ubuntu 20.04), then it works fine: there is an issue *exactly* with my home computer, sadly!

Comment: I interpreted Ethernet Wireless as having both but apparently not.  Try:   Turn on the printer and access the Wireless Settings menu. Select the HP Envy 4500 wireless setup Wizard option to activate the Wi-Fi. A list of networks available within the printer's Wi-Fi range appears

Comment: As I said, the printer does see my network, but when I insert the password, it doesn't connect. I tried this countless times. Nor does WPS work. This is a problem with my modem/router, because with my previous modem/router it did work. I can not change the modem/router.